# To configure Docker to use different network interfaces on a host with multiple network interfaces?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

To configure Docker to use different network interfaces on a host with multiple network interfaces, and using Docker Compose to start services with host network mode

How to solve ; By default, when starting, it uses the IP of ens0. But I want to communicate with ens192.

Comment: maybe this article will help
https://labs.iximiuz.com/tutorials/container-networking-from-scratch

Comment: When you publish a port, the `docker run -p` and Compose `ports:` settings take an optional IP address that's the (existing host) IP address to bind to; so you could `docker run -p 192.168.1.2:12345:6789` to choose a specific host IP/port to use.  Does that help?  You should not normally be using host networking, especially on a multi-homed system.